# Select : Summarize values and Group by Date

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select

So my objective is to SUM my values and group them by date.

At first I just wrote it with the date provided but I need to provide `SUM` with `YY-MM-DD`, `YY-MM` and `YYYY` format.

```
SELECT Table1.Date, Concat(Round(SUM((ISNULL(Price.Morning,0) + ISNULL(Price.Day,0) + ISNULL(Price.Evening,0))*Tickets.count),2),' €') AS 'Total' 
FROM Table1
JOIN Tickets ON Tickets.Table1_ID = Table1.Table1_ID
JOIN Price ON Tickets.Price_ID = Price.Price_ID 
GROUP BY Table1.Date
;
```

And it looks like this:

[image: And it looks like this]

And now I've got as far as this:

```
SELECT Cast(Tabl1.Date as Date) AS 'Date', Concat(Round(SUM((ISNULL(Price.Morning,0) + ISNULL(Price.Day,0) + ISNULL(Price.Evening,0))*Tickets.Count),2),' €') AS 'Total'
FROM Table1
JOIN Tickets ON Tickets.Table1_ID = Table1.Table1_ID
JOIN Price ON Tickets.Price_ID = Price.Price_ID
GROUP BY Date;
```

And i get this:

[image: And i get this]

All the `...Concat(Round(SUM((ISNULL(Price.Morning,0) + ISNULL(Price.Day,0) + ISNULL(Price.Evening,0))*Tickets.Count),2),' €') AS 'Total'...` is necessary because in the database there are `NULL` values, thats why I use the `ISNULL` function and `0` in case it is `NULL` because otherwise it breaks all the calculations.

You can see that table here:

[image: This is the table with Prices]

Comment: `ISNULL(Price.Evening,0)` should be `IFNULL(Price.Evening,0)`. `ISNULL()` just returne TRUE or FALSE, `IFNULL()` returns the first argument, but uses the second as a default when the first is null.

Comment: You should be getting an error from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get something like what you want using a `GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP`. Without any sample data it's hard to be 100% certain but this query should work. Note that you can use [`COALESCE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) to select the non-NULL value in the prices without using an `IFNULL` on each of them.

```
SELECT YEAR(Table1.Date) AS year
     , MONTH(Table1.Date) AS month
     , DAY(Table1.Date) AS day
     , Round(SUM(COALESCE(Price.Morning, Price.Day, Price.Evening) * Tickets.count), 2) AS 'Total' 
FROM Table1
JOIN Tickets ON Tickets.Table1_ID = Table1.Table1_ID
JOIN Price ON Tickets.Price_ID = Price.Price_ID 
GROUP BY year, month, day WITH Rollup
```

This should give you a table that looks something like this:

```
year    month   day     Total
2017    7       24      476.00
2017    7       26      1992.20
2017    7       30      877.50
2017    7               3345.70
2017    8       2       2362.40
2017    8               2362.40
2017                    5708.10
                        5708.10
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `GROUP BY Date` is grouping by the `Date` column in the table, not the `Date` alias. Change it to:

```
GROUP BY DATE(Date)
```

Comment: When i try this i get error "there are no built-in functions" or something like that

Comment: Are you sure you're using MySQL, not another DBMS like SQL-Server?

Answer (score 0):

Modified your query (changed IsNull to IfNull) and group by on date as:

```
SELECT DATE(Table1.Date) myDate, Concat(Round(SUM((IFNULL(Price.Morning,0) + IFNULL(Price.Day,0) + IFNULL(Price.Evening,0))*Tickets.count),2),' €') AS 'Total' 
FROM Table1
JOIN Tickets ON Tickets.Table1_ID = Table1.Table1_ID
JOIN Price ON Tickets.Price_ID = Price.Price_ID 
GROUP BY myDate;
```